# How to Connect Togglable Vertical Tabs using mysql php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

i found  Vertical Tabs in html on internet.so i want connect mysql database using php.
iam creating php code this not work properly. iam using button type for selection. so How to Connect Togglable Vertical Tabs in mysql php

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
    * {box-sizing: border-box}
    body {font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;}

    /* Style the tab */
    .tab {
        float: left;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        width: 30%;
        height: 300px;
    }

    /* Style the buttons inside the tab */
    .tab button {
        display: block;
        background-color: inherit;
        color: black;
        padding: 22px 16px;
        width: 100%;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        text-align: left;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: 0.3s;
        font-size: 17px;
    }

    /* Change background color of buttons on hover */
    .tab button:hover {
        background-color: #ddd;
    }

    /* Create an active/current "tab button" class */
    .tab button.active {
        background-color: #ccc;
    }

    /* Style the tab content */
    .tabcontent {
        float: left;
        padding: 0px 12px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        width: 70%;
        border-left: none;
        height: 300px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <p>Click on the buttons inside the tabbed menu:</p>

    <div class="tab">
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')" id="defaultOpen">London</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
    </div>

    <div id="London" class="tabcontent">
      <h3>London</h3>
      <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
      <h3>Paris</h3>
      <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
    </div>

    <div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
      <h3>Tokyo</h3>
      <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
    </div>

    <script>
    function openCity(evt, cityName) {
        var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
        tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
        for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
            tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
        for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
            tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
        evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
    }

    // Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
    document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

i want connecting in mysql database using php
mysql database like

```
id | country  | ciy       | Decs
-------------------------------------
1  | England  | london    |London is the capital city of England
2  | France   | paris     |Paris is the capital of France.  
3  | Japan    | tokiyo    |Tokyo is the capital of Japan
```

iam trying to php code Not Work 
php code here...

```
<?php 
$query= "select city from table" ;
$res= mysql_query($query) ;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{


?>

  <button class="tablinks" onClick="openCity(event, '<?php echo $row['city'] ;?>')"><?php echo $row['city']; ?></button>
</div>


<?php } ?>


<div id="<?php echo $row['desc'] ; ?>" class="tabcontent">
<p><?php $row['decs'] ; ?> <p> </div>
```